# ¿Funciona `atexit` al apagarse bruscamente un equipo que esta ejecutando un programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulos

Tengo una duda para los que usaron el modulo `atexit` de python, ya sabeis que este modulo usa el metodo `register(function)` para ejecutar una funcion justo antes de terminar un programa y esto funciona en distintos escenarios como:

- Cerrar la terminal cuando el programa aun se esta ejecutando.
- Presionar control C enviando una senal **KeyboardInterrupt**.
- Presionar control D provocando un **EOFError**.
- El programa termina normalmente.

Pues quisiera saber si esto también funciona en el escenario de que el equipo se quede sin energia y por tanto se apague inmediatamente, o por ejemplo que alguien desconecte el equipo  cuando el programa aun se ejecuta.

Comment: At normal program termination (for instance, if sys.exit() is called or the main module’s execution completes), all functions registered are called in last in, first out order. The assumption is that lower level modules will normally be imported before higher level modules and thus must be cleaned up later.

Comment: También puedes escribir un programa y comprobarlo por ti mismo.

Comment: No veo tiempo material suficiente para que el programa se entere que va a haber un corte de corriente. Tendría que estar el sistema preparado con una SAI que avise del corte al sistema operativo para que haga un cierre ordenado y avise al intérprete de python. Si no tienes una SAI, puedes olvidarse de que se ejecute el `atexit`.